Redirection of a WordPress post without plugin or htaccess
Our WordPress site was hacked (They were able to create an Administrator user). We took it back but we noticed a 301 redirection for one of the blog posts. We are trying to remove this redirection. Observations:

Even if we remove the post, redirection is still there
Nothing in .htaccess file about this
Nothing in theme functions.php file
We have the Redirection plugin but there is no entry about that post there
When it is redirected to an external site, the domain stays the same (our own domain)

Any ideas about how they did it and how we can remove this redirection?

Check the cache of your browser, i don't know if they've maybe accessed server files but check the index.php and other files for code injection.

And the nginx or apache config

Found a folder with the post's permalink in the site's root folder. We didn't think they had access to the server but apparently they did

While you are in there, check the cron file and shell files like .bashrc to see if you find anything nefarious in there, too. Also scan uploads for PHP and PHTML files to make sure re-entry isn't possible.

Do not attempt to "clean" an infected website or server. Find a known good backup, delete everything on the server (ideally, build a completely new virtual machine) and restore the backup. If someone has had Administrator access to the server, they could have left multiple pieces of malicious software in place, feeding them all your private data, or waiting for them to come back and log in again.

To put it another way, nuke it from orbit, it's the only way to be sure.
